# Scrolling issue in iPhone app running on 3GS

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, scroll

The below method is causing the Scrolling problem when i run it on my iPhone 3S. I know we can increase the performance of Scrolling but don't know how to do it even after searching a lot on the net and tried several things.

I have come across making cells opaque and/or making Table views as Sub views to greatly increase the Scrolling performance if someone can modify the below code or just point what needs to change in the below code.
My code is below.

```
// cell is created for each row of track.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    NSLog(@"tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath");


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [CellIdentifier release];
    cell.accessoryView = nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                                        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

     /** saving the data in Book structure.**/
     Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     [cell.textLabel setText: aBook.name];

    // indexrow refers to each cell 
    temp =[appDelegate.tracklocation intValue];
    requesttemp =[appDelegate.requestlocation intValue];        

    // Coloring Code starts
    // indexPath starts from 0th cell that is why it is incremented by 1
    if(temp==(indexPath.row+1))
    { 
        NSLog(@"value of temp inside if is = %d",temp);
        NSLog(@"value of indexrow inside if is=%d",(indexPath.row+1));
        UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"speaker.png"]];
        imageView1.backgroundColor = [ UIColor greenColor ];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor greenColor ];
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor] ];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor] ];
        cell.accessoryView = imageView1;
        [imageView1 release];
    }
    else 
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor whiteColor ];
        [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor] ];
        [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor ]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor] ];
    }

        while(requesttemp>temp)
        { 
            if (requesttemp==(indexPath.row+1))
            {
                if (colorflag==1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"value of request temp inside while is = %d",requesttemp);
                    NSLog(@"value of indexrow inside while is=%d",(indexPath.row+1));
                    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor blueColor ];
                    [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor ]];
                    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor ]];
                    [cell.detailTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor] ];
                    [cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor] ];
                }
            }
            requesttemp=requesttemp-1;
        }
    }    

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = abook.artist;

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

     cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
     NSLog(@"RootViewController cellForRowAtIndexPath %@ ",cell);

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: iPhone 3S does not exsist, it's a 3GS. [face palm];

Comment: @maddy2011 : your acceptance ration is very poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cellIdentifier release] ??
You don't release statics !!
Your cell reuse is probably failing because of it.

Also there is no autorelease on UITableViewCell allocation. This should be causing lots of leaks and ultimately slow down / crash the app as well.

This is a deadly combination of leak + cell reuse failure

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have changed the code accordingly and will test this case once I get my device back.


One more thing to notice in the code is that the  `*abook` object that I am using
`Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` 
 is declared as a **Structure**. Will this cause any slowness in getting the record and then assigning it to a cell as opposed to using an Array?

Comment: It should not matter. Mixing C should not cause any performance problems unless you are doing "pass by value" somewhere.
This line of code seems ok to me.

Comment: Ok. I changed the 2 lines  in the above code and scrolling improved a lot

Comment: Ok. I changed the 2 lines in the above code and scrolling improved a lot. 
 `[CellIdentifier release];`
 `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

There are other memory leaks elsewhere in the code as well which is causing some scrolling issues and also maybe because it is coloring the cells again and again which maybe causing the slowness in smoothness of scrolling. I will need to check this out. Thanks. Anyone wants to comment on this point then i will appreciate it.

Comment: The point you mentioned really worked. It's running fine now after I commented  `[CellIdentifier release];`. Thanks.